# Installing SQL Server 2014 Data Tools BI for VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools

I have VS 2013 Professional 64bit, SSMS 2014.  I've downloaded SSDTBI_x86_ENU and ran the setup.  According to the instructions from others who have had errors during installation, I'm supposed to select 'New Instance' and not 'Add Features' in 'Install Types'.  I don't seem to have this option.  So, I select 'New SQL Server stand-alone installation or add features to an existing installation'.

At this point I do get a feature selection window where I can select 'SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence'.

After clicking next, during the install, I will get the following Error:

> 'VS Shell installation has failed with exit code -2147205120'

If I click on the link it takes me to a MS web page with the following information...

> Details
>
> ID: 50000
>
> Source: setup.rll
>
> ### We're sorry
>
> There is no additional information about this issue in the Error and Event Log Messages or Knowledge Base databases at this time. You can use the links in the Support area to determine whether any additional information might be available elsewhere.
>
> ---
>
> Thank you for searching on this message; your search helps us identify those areas for which we need to provide more information.

Anyone know what I can do to get this to install?

Comment: Possibly related: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15716.visual-studio-2012-and-the-error-code-2147205120.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I had to download and install VS 2012 Tools for Applications and VS 2012 Shell Isolated, then install Business Intelligence.